# Why would people want a dragon dead?

Tags: science-based, dragons

It's probably a bit story-based, but I just couldn't come up with a legitimate reason.

There is this dragon, called Gyvaris. Now, he is a roughly horse-sized creature with formidable, but not impenetratable armor and incredibly good agility. Awesome in combat but nowhere near the decimates-armies-for-fun type. The closest approximation would be the mixture of a [night fury](https://howtotrainyourdragon.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Fury) and [Joseph Joestar](https://jojo.fandom.com/wiki/Joseph_Joestar).

In a shellnut, Gyvaris is an egotistic and fairly smart dragon who would rather prefer to avoid humans and when threathened by a force, larger than he could handle, he says "Nigerundayo!" and flees. Albeit he doesn't hoard in a conventional sense, he does have things he wouldn't let go of: His home, a cave in the woods, and his freedom.

Initially, the conflict between him and humans would stem fom Gyv occasionally stealing food from humans. This, however, isn't sound, as capturing/killing/chasing away Gyvaris would take more resources than what is lost during his raids.

Human society is medieval but, thanks to magic (that's secretly technology), they can pretty much **null and void any potential famine.**

As far as they know, Gyvaris is a mentally unstable dragon and is the only dragon they know of.

Dragon organs/parts are USELESS and everyone knows that. Similar creations of Demiurge (Anon) involuntarily release an enzyme upon death that would normally help break down and reassembe graphene in their body. Left unchecked, these enzymes rapidly reduce the strength of internal parts.

As for scales, they are awesome because of how they protect every centimeter of the dragon without hindering its movements. Otherwise, it's no real improvement compared to human armor.

**What would a logical reason be for humans to try killing Gyvaris? What would be the biggest benefit from it for humans as a collective?**

- It has to benefit a large group of humans
- Benefits must outweigh potential risks

Comment: "_Dragon organs/parts are USELESS and everyone knows that._" aren't your dragons made largely of extremely strong and resilient materials, making them largely indestructable as far as medieval weaponry goes? They'd spot that soon enough, and that's gotta pique _somebody_'s interest.

Comment: Also, if he is the only known dragon, how do they know his 'parts' are useless?

Comment: Dragons are pretty well known for eating all the virgins it can find.... seems like a good reason.

Comment: An interesting question: what logical reason does one sophont have to murder another sophont.  Murder rarely has a truly logical component to it (apart from the twisted logic of the muderer's own devising). I'm not really clear on what you're asking or what it has to do with worldbuilding per se.  (And yes, your question is story based, so I'd leave it closed.)

Answer (score 9):

### Killing livestock is more than enough reason.

I think you underestimate how much damage killing livestock could do to a medieval settlement. 1 cow would be worth as much as two years rent on a cottage. Image what you would do to an animal that cost you two years rent, now image it has done this to several people in the neighborhood, then consider there is no idea of animal rights or sympathy to mitigate the reaction. One or two cows alone would warrant its death. If you live in an agricultural community and something kills even one of your livestock you come down on it like a ton of bricks, these places don't have a lot of food surplus to begin with.

But there will also be a feedback loop, once it kills any livestock then after that any dead livestock is the fault of the dragon, gods help him if a child goes missing. Humans are not the most rational creatures. There is a reason wolves were hunted nearly to extinction.

[medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html –](http://I%20think%20you%20underestimate%20how%20much%20damage%20killing%20livestock%20could%20do%20to%20a%20medieval%20settlement.%201%20cow%20would%20be%20worth%20as%20much%20as%20two%20years%20rent%20on%20a%20cottage.%20Image%20what%20you%20would%20do%20to%20an%20animal%20that%20cost%20you%20two%20years%20rent,%20now%20image%20it%20has%20done%20this%20to%20several%20people%20in%20the%20neighborhood.%20There%20is%20a%20reason%20wolves%20were%20hunted%20nearly%20to%20extinction.%20medieval.ucdavis.edu/120D/Money.html%20%E2%80%93)

Comment: "The dragons/jews/communists/fascists/anarcho capitalists/immigrants/emigrants ate my homework"

Comment: Basically: Gyv has been starving for a while and couldn't find a single deer or even rabit to eat. He the spots a large flock of sheep "Jackpot" he thinks. He swoops down and shatters the skull of an older sheep with the spade on his tail and gobbles it up in one sitting. He then retreats to the forest. Weeks go by without anything of note happening, until he gets ambushed by a group of soldiers. Severly wounded and confused, he barely manages to get away alive...

Comment: @Mephistopheles no deer and no rabbits? that'll teach him to be sedentary. And in the middle of some kind of ecological catastrophe.

Comment: Correct, a single horse in some locales could be worth a small herd of cows and the farmers daughter. In others fenced in sheep are a lot easier to catch than rabbits and deer. A single cow might be a families only wealth or critical to surviving winter. Times could be tough.

Answer (score 8):

In many culture killing a big/dangerous animal was a show of manliness and strength. Even in out days, who would brag about killing a bug? Nobody. But there are people who pay big money for having the possibility of having on social media their picture with a hunted down lion/bear/etc.

This is also the reason you are looking for. Only a true man can kill the dragon.

Comment: Given the nature of the OP's dragons, the number of "true men" will turn out to be zero, and the ratio of sensible men to foolhardy idiots will rise until the idiots run out or it dawns upon them that they need a better test of manhood that doesn't involve getting incinerated.

Comment: @StarfishPrime, when I was a kid in my home town there was a prehistoric megalithic structure, passed intact over the millennia. A couple of youngsters decided that spraying graffiti was not enough to stand out from the crowd, and one night they demolished it, bragging about it the next days. Unicity of the target is an incentive rather than a obstacle.

Comment: @L.Dutch Except a megalithic structure doesn't shott fireballs or scream "Get the f@ck out of my house!" A retired, but still very capable, grumy marine would be a better analogy.

Comment: @Mephistopheles * shoot * grumpy.

Answer (score 3):

When a would-be leader wants to unite the people behind himself, one way to do so is to play up an external threat. A power-hungry demagogue could arise, playing up the differences between us and the evil monster in the woods. For historical reference please see Disney's "Beauty and the Beast".